# How do I arrange an array as table rows?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to learn the Ruby way of array processing.  What is a succinct way to write the following function?

```
def columnize(items, n_cols)
```

Items is a 1D array of arbitrary length. I want to return an array of rows, each having a length of `n_cols`, that includes all of the `items` column-wise, possibly with `nil`s padding the last column. For example:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
table = columnize items, 3
```

This should produce a `table` of:

```
[[1, 4, 7], 
 [2, 5, nil], 
 [3, 6, nil]]
```

Note that it's possible for the last column to be all `nil`s as in:

```
columnize [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4
```

This is a real problem I need to solve for report generation. I have a Ruby newbie solution that is not very satisfying and can post it if desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for filling rows that only have `nil` elements, this will do:

```
first, *rest = items.each_slice((items.length/n_cols).ceil).to_a
first.zip(*rest)
```

Comment: If it walks like a matrix and quacks like a matrix, it should be a matrix :-)

Comment: It's actually an HTML table.  The array of arrays is a better match for this problem, @mudasobwa.

Comment: [`Matrix#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-to_a) gives you an array of arrays, if you need no other `Matrix` out-of-the-box features. Plus the @sawa’s code fails when `n_cols > items.size` (giving array of less size, than requested,) while mine is still working.

Comment: @sawa now that I look at it closely this doesn't work right.  The value of `n_cols` should be the number of columns in the result and with your code it's the number of rows.  You'd think there would be a simple formula to get columns from rows, but in fact it's not trivial. The case with 9 elements and 4 rows is an example.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [`Matrix`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class.

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
require 'matrix'
# ⇒ true
m = Matrix.build(3) { |row, col| items[row+col*3] }
# ⇒ Matrix[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, nil], [3, 6, nil]]
```

Comment: Nice to know about Matrix.  Thanks. +1

Comment: @Gene: mudasobwa is right in many things he says, but do not believe him completely when he says that you need Matrix class. That depends on your usecase. For example, Matrix instances are immutable, they behave more or less as more advanced kind of numbers. Matrix is more cumbersome to use than Array, and when it comes to high-performance computations, there is this nascent SciRuby project with its NMatrix class, supposed to be taking use of a low-level library in C or Fortran (I forgot which) for matrix math.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I never said “need,” I said “want to.” There is definitely no high-performance computation expected (and, btw, array of arrays is not the best choice for _computations_ as well.) It looks a bit strange to mention the specific math here. Two dimentional array is actually a matrix and unless you are computing the Pluto’s precession of the equinoxes you are to use the standard classes, rathen than 3rd parties.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Your answer is very good, my attitude to it is commendatory, with marginalia. Talking about numerical performance is my personal idiosyncrasy, and I meant speed, not decimal precision. The latter one can easily achieve even with Marc-Andre's Matrix, as long as one fills it with Shigeo Kobayashi's BigDecimal instances :-)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky it looks like your comment forces the topic starter to choose the unmaintainable *prove-of-i-can-do-it-with-arrays* solution :-) I understand pretty fine that there are circumstances when I’ll be the first person to avoid 3rd-parties to reinvent a wheel which is a 1nm roundlier.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's Array class has [`transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) which is designed to convert rows into columns. Using it in conjunction with [`fill`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-fill) and Enumerable's [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) gives:

```
require 'pp'

def columnize(items, cols)
  ary = items.dup.fill(nil, items.size, cols - items.size % cols )
  ary.each_slice(ary.size / cols).to_a.transpose
end 

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
pp columnize(items, 3)
pp columnize [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4
```

Which outputs:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, nil], [3, 6, nil]]
[[1, 4, 7, nil], [2, 5, 8, nil], [3, 6, 9, nil]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate this. It's similar to my first try except that I was using the wrong set of ruby docs and so did not know `each_slice` existed and coded my own.